# Storing Information in an Address Book

Tags: java, arraylist

I am required to make an address book application without the use of databases (on memory). I have decided to use ArrayLists to do so. But the problem is that once I input a new name/contact, it overrides any other contacts that I "stored" (or thought I stored) before. I have been trying to figure it out and am outright confused.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    firstActions();
}

static String firstName;
static String lastName;
static String phoneNumber;
static String search = null; 
static public int choice = 0;
static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
static ContactInformation contact;
static ArrayList<String> information = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void firstActions()

{
    System.out.println("Address Book Menu: What would you like to do? 1) Input data. 2) Search data. 3) Close.");
    choice = input.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        inputData();
    case 2:
            System.out.println("Search by: 1) First Name 2) Last Name 3) Phone Number 4) Zip Code.");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                searchName();
                break;
            case 2:
                searchLastName();
            case 3:
                searchPhoneNumber();
            case 4:
                //execute search by Zip Code
            default:
                System.out.println("Please compile again.");
                break;
            }
            break;
    case 3:
            System.out.println("Application terminated.");
            System.exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("Please compile again.");
        break;
    }

}
public static void inputData ()
{
    information = new ArrayList<String>();
    contact = new ContactInformation(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, information);
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    contact.setFirstName(input.next());
    information.add(contact.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    contact.setLastName(input.next());
    information.add(contact.getLastName());
    System.out.println("What is your phone number?");
    contact.setPhoneNumber(input.next());
    information.add(contact.getPhoneNumber());
    System.out.println("Saved.");
    System.out.println("What would you like to do next?");
    firstActions();
}
public static void searchName()
{
    System.out.println("What is the first name you are looking for?");
    search = input.next();
    if (search.equals(information.get(0)))
            {
                System.out.println(information);
                System.out.println("What would you like to do next?");
                firstActions();
            }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This person is not saved in the address book. Please try again.");
        firstActions();
    }
}
public static void searchLastName()
    {
        System.out.println("What is the last name you are looking for?");
        search = input.next();
        if (search.equals(information.get(1)))
                {
                    System.out.println(information);
                    firstActions();
                }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("This person is not saved in the address book. Please try again.");
            firstActions();
        }
}
public static void searchPhoneNumber()
{
    System.out.println("What is the last name you are looking for?");
    search = input.next();
    if (search.equals(information.get(2)))
            {
                System.out.println(information);
                firstActions();
            }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("This person is not saved in the address book. Please try again.");
        firstActions();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my contact information class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ContactInformation {

public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public String phoneNumber;
ArrayList <String> information = new ArrayList<String> ();

public ContactInformation(String firstName, String lastName,
        String phoneNumber, ArrayList<String> information) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.information = information;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}
public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: You keep creating a new array list instead of using a single one.

Comment: But wouldn't I need to create a new array since I am adding new contacts?

Comment: No, you'd add new information to an existing array list. Otherwise you're losing all references to the information already in it.

Comment: I think you need to sit back and think about your design of this program first. Do some research on how methods are invoked, and their expected behavior.

Comment: also, don't call firstActions() in inputData(), you are recursing every time. use a loop and break after inputData(). And read answers to solve the problem of your question

Comment: @user2727165 The question we're basically asking is; what are you using to store the information you had before? If you're using that array to store information about *one* person, what are you doing to store the information of *multiple*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first create the ArrayList here:

`static ArrayList<String> information = new ArrayList<String>();`

but every time you go to the `inputData()` method, you create a NEW ArrayList:

`information = new ArrayList<String>();`

From how you wrote the code, I would assume you have a `ContactInformation` object that you should be placing into the ArrayList.

Change the ArrayList to: `static ArrayList<ContactInformation> information = new ArrayList<ContactInformation>();`

Then you can create each object and ADD the object to the ArrayList INSTEAD of all the information separately.

EDIT:

Your "ContactInformation" object contains `String` variables. After you add this object to the ArrayList, you can use a loop to find if the data in the object matches what you are looking for. It should look something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i != information.size(); i++) {
    if (information.get(i).getFirstName().matches(search)) {                
        System.out.println("found");
    }
}
```

The `if statement` says that `"if the element 'i's variable 'firstName' in ArrayList 'information' matches the variable 'search', print the word 'found'."`

You can obviously change what happens if the name is found, I just simplified it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I overlooked that. This will definitely fix it.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting. I am still getting the same results.

Comment: You have several errors in your code, any number of them could still be causing the problem. This is simply a solution to the question you asked.

Comment: As for my search functionality, is there a way to actually look through each contact instance stored within the ArrayList to check if firstName ever matches?

Comment: @user2727165 I edited my post to answer your question. Also, make sure to "accept" my answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I eventually thought about it and basically did what you did, just with a different for loop.

Answer (score 0):

everytime you want to insert a name you are creating a new Object from ArrayList

```
 information = new ArrayList<String>();
```

initizalize this arraylist in your main method and then access it via its variable(information)

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is with the first line in your inputData() method:

```
information = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You're creating a new  ArrayList object every time the method is called, which means the old object, and the data it contained, is lost.